# Pause guard using a system wide keyboard shortcut (OSX)?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, guard

I use the phantastic Guard gem to do BDD in Rails. It's great that it executes all my specs etc. automatically after changing a file, but there are times where I don't want them to run immediately, and I pause Guard by pressing <kbd>P</kbd> in the console. But after several times, this becomes tedious, and it would be nicer to have a system wide keyboard shortcut or something to tell Guard to pause/unpause.

Anybody has an idea on how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea, but I'm unable to test if it works, since I enjoy my holiday and the data plan I quite expensive, so I try to limit my Internet usage.

You can execute a shell script like it's described under [Fast User Switching/Apple Menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/45740/fast-user-switching-apple-menu/46308#46308). The script itself could [send a signal to Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard#signals) to start/stop the listener.

**Update:**

The following script has been developed in [Guard issue #303](https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/303).

```
local FILE = "/tmp/.guardpaused"
if [ -f FILE ]; then
  ps -ef | grep -i guard | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -USR2
  rm FILE
  echo "Unpaused files modification listening."
else
  ps -ef | grep -i guard | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -USR1
  touch FILE
  echo "Paused files modification listening."
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought of something like that myself already. I'm using [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/), a very nice launcher (like Quicksilver, but lightweight), which allows me to define system wide shortcuts to start an AppleScript. I will look into it in the coming days I guess (I haven't done anything with AppleScript yet).

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot. Thank you, it's working like a charm! :)